# Depth Camera flickering

Tags: ros-noetic, point-cloud

https://youtu.be/GSPXaIzbav4

I use Gemini E Depth Camera and just test to view point cloud.
But Camera is flickering.
I think it needs to adjust shutter_speed.
Can you think another problems?
Help me.

Comment: That may be normal for that sensor.  It's hard to tell how bad it is from the video of rviz (using the axes color instead of rgb color may help), can you share a bag of a few seconds of output from the camera?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eM_PycaD7N9748LJBXDC0L-hqCQfASnQ/view?usp=drive_link

here is my bag file.

Answer (score 0):

The frame-to-frame movement of points on the surfaces in the point clouds look like normal noise.  The points move around a little but they are still very close to what appear to be flat surfaces.

The visible light image looks over-exposed for the closest surfaces to the camera, if you can reduce the exposure time you may get a higher frame-rate out of it as well- then the noise will blend together more.

The IR image is completely black as seen in rqt, rqt_image_view doesn't have the controls to make it visible- another node that transforms it into an 8-bit image from `mono16` could help, and once the details are visible they could be used to help debug issues.

There is a stair step pattern apparent on the surfaces that is due to quantization, but probably unavoidable for this type of camera.

The default drawn point size for PointCloud2 in rviz is too big for how close the camera is to the target surfaces- 0.001 works better.

The biggest concern are the irregular gaps between the frames in the bag, and there's a long gap with no updates at all in the middle, but your youtube video doesn't match that (though the gaps between frames are large, which points to the shutter speed/exposure like you originally suggested)- that may be a an issue with rosbag recording and not the camera and driver.

[image: gemini e depth camera]